# Is there a way to order this list in a specific way?

Tags: python, sorting

So I have this list:

```
[7, 31, 31, 61, 61, 79, 29, 79, 29, 103, 37, 103, 37, 47, 47, 53, 53, 89, 5, 89, 5, 13, 13, 83, 83, 101, 53, 101, 17, 53, 11, 17, 11, 59, 17, 59, 17, 41, 41, 79, 79, 97, 3, 97, 3, 41, 19, 41, 19, 53, 53, 67, 29, 67, 29, 73, 23, 73, 23, 43, 43, 71]
```

And I would like to know if there was a way to order them such as the last element of a pair is the first of the second pair, just like this:

```
[7, 31, 31, 61, 61, 79, 79, 29, 29, 103, 103, 37 ....]
[pair1] [pair2] [pair3] [pair4] [pair5]  [pair6] ...
```

Is there a way to do this?

I've tried for loops but it just has a very high time complexity.

here's my code:

```
lis=[7, 31, 31, 61, 61, 79, 29, 79, 29, 103, 37, 103, 37, 47, 47, 53, 53, 89, 5, 89, 5, 13, 13, 83, 83, 101, 53, 101, 17, 53, 11, 17, 11, 59, 17, 59, 17, 41, 41, 79, 79, 97, 3, 97, 3, 41, 19, 41, 19, 53, 53, 67, 29, 67, 29, 73, 23, 73, 23, 43, 43, 71]
for i in range(0, len(lis)-4,4):
    if lis[i]==lis[i+2]:
        p=lis[i]
        lis[i]=lis[i+1]
        lis[i+1]=p
    elif lis[i]==lis[i+3]:
        p = lis[i]
        lis[i] = lis[i + 1]
        lis[i + 1] = p
        p=lis[i+2]
        lis[i+2]=lis[i+3]
        lis[i+3]=p
    elif lis[i+1]==lis[i+3]:
        p=lis[i+2]
        lis[i+2]=lis[i+3]
        lis[i+3]=p
print(lis)
```

Comment: Please add the code, what have you tried so far.

Comment: *"last element of a pair is the first of the second pair"* huh! What? Can you make that clear?

Comment: Are you sure that there are at least enough pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, like `sort`ing based on the `index` in the original `list`,

```
>>> x
[7, 31, 31, 61, 61, 79, 29, 79, 29, 103, 37, 103, 37, 47, 47, 53, 53, 89, 5, 89, 5, 13, 13, 83, 83, 101, 53, 101, 17, 53, 11, 17, 11, 59, 17, 59, 17, 41, 41, 79, 79, 97, 3, 97, 3, 41, 19, 41, 19, 53, 53, 67, 29, 67, 29, 73, 23, 73, 23, 43, 43, 71]

# the `sorted` function takes a `key` function, that one can use to manipulate how the sort should be based on
# In this case, you could use `index` of the `element` in the `list` `x`,
# So, while the sort goes through each element, it check against the index in the original list, which is `x, thus it aligns each item based on the `index`.
>>> sorted(x, key=x.index) # note that you have more than a pair, so :)
[7, 31, 31, 61, 61, 79, 79, 79, 79, 29, 29, 29, 29, 103, 103, 37, 37, 47, 47, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 89, 89, 5, 5, 13, 13, 83, 83, 101, 101, 17, 17, 17, 17, 11, 11, 59, 59, 41, 41, 41, 41, 97, 97, 3, 3, 19, 19, 67, 67, 73, 73, 23, 23, 43, 43, 71]
```

If you really care for a `pair` then,

```
>>> data = []
>>> for k in sorted(x, key=x.index): # `using direct x.index instead of useless lambda(i previously used) in this case, as @Austin suggested
...   if data.count(k) < 2: # add the element until it reaches count 2, which is `pair`, which is what you asked for
...     data.append(k)
... 
>>> data
[7, 31, 31, 61, 61, 79, 79, 29, 29, 103, 103, 37, 37, 47, 47, 53, 53, 89, 89, 5, 5, 13, 13, 83, 83, 101, 101, 17, 17, 11, 11, 59, 59, 41, 41, 97, 97, 3, 3, 19, 19, 67, 67, 73, 73, 23, 23, 43, 43, 71]
```

**Reasoning:**

> `list.index` will `return` the first matching `index`. Say you have a `list`, `x = [1,2,1,3]` and `x.index(1)` will always `return` `0`. Thus it will be `sorted` differently if one use `list.index` as the keyfunc for `sort`ing

Comment: Shorter:. `sorted(x, key=x.index)`.

Comment: @Austin Updated as per the suggestion. Thanks. `lambda`s are my `goto` keyfunc, nowadays :). Sorry

Comment: Could you expand your answer to explain how this works?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Updated. Should i add more ? Please let me know

Comment: Sorry but your addition didn't really clarify anything. _Why_ does sorting by the original index work? Wouldn't sorting based on the original index just give you, well, the same list back? I mean clearly it didn't but I don't understand why and your answer doesn't explain it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It won't give the same `list` back, because `list.index` will return the `first` matching `index`. Say you have a list `x = [1,2,1,3]` and `x.index(1)` will always return `0`. Thus it will be `sorted`ed differently if one use `list.index` as the `key`func for `sort`ing

Comment: Ah, so `x.index(y)` gives you the position of the first element matching `y` inside `x`? Okay, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to transpose the second and third elements if the first and third are equal. You'd do something like:

```
i = 0
while i < len(seq) - 2:
    if seq[i] == seq[i + 2]:
        # Swap the next two elements
        seq[i + 1], seq[i + 2] = seq[i + 2], seq[i + 1]
        i = i + 3
        continue
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: I was going to say that this isn't even valid Python (on account of `++i`) but then I realized that `++i` is, in fact, valid Python.  It just doesn't do what one might think it does. :)

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty sloppy solution, but it should do your job.

First of we chunk your data into pairs of two and then we will sort these two pairs.

```py
data = [7, 31, 31, 61, 61, 79, 29, 79, 29, 103, 37, 103, 37, 47, 47, 53, 53, 89, 5, 89, 5, 13, 13, 83, 83, 101, 53, 101, 17, 53, 11, 17, 11, 59, 17, 59, 17, 41, 41, 79, 79, 97, 3, 97, 3, 41, 19, 41, 19, 53, 53, 67, 29, 67, 29, 73, 23, 73, 23, 43, 43, 71]

def chunks(l, n):
    # For item i in a range that is a length of l,
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        # Create an index range for l of n items:
        yield l[i:i+n]

sliced_list = list(chunks(data, 2))

ordered_list = []

for a in sliced_list:
    # Sort the pairs
    ordered_list.append([a[0], a[1]] if a[0] < a[1] else [a[1], a[0]])

print(ordered_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another crappy solution

```
import numpy as np
alist=np.array([7, 31, 31, 61, 61, 79, 29, 79, 29, 103, 37, 103, 37, 47, 47, 53, 53, 89, 5, 89, 5, 13, 13, 83, 83, 101, 53, 101, 17, 53, 11, 17, 11, 59, 17, 59, 17, 41, 41, 79, 79, 97, 3, 97, 3, 41, 19, 41, 19, 53, 53, 67, 29, 67, 29, 73, 23, 73, 23, 43, 43, 71])
l=alist.reshape(-1,2)

for row in range(1,len(l)):
    if abs(l[row-1,1]-l[row,1])<=abs(l[row-1,1]-l[row,0]):
        l[row]=np.roll(l[row],1)
```